# calculate a state variable using another state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I would like to calculate the pf of salary using the basic salary like this:

```
state = {
        fgsSalary: 0,
        basicSalary: 0,
        //pf: this.state.basicSalary * 0.12
        //pf: this.basicSalary * 0.12
        //pf: basicSalary * 0.12
}
```

I tried all three ways but nothing works.
If there's any way please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), benefits you to access property as a property:

```js
var state = {
  fgsSalary: 1,
  basicSalary: 2,
  get pf() {
    return this.basicSalary * 0.12
  }
};
console.log(state.pf);
```